# Multiple Images in NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, camera, nsmutablearray

I am saving images from the camera in an NSMutableArray. When I add one picture, the picture is added to the array. But, the problem is that when I take another picture, the first picture is replaced by the second one. I want to save all of the pictures taken by the camera.

```
- (IBAction)takePhoto {
    UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    picker.delegate = self;
    picker.allowsEditing = YES;
    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;

    [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];
}

- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
    UIImage *cameraImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
    self.tempView.image = cameraImage;
    camImages = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:10];
    [camImages addObject:self.tempView.image];
    //self.chosenImages=camImages;
    NSLog(@"the image is=%@",camImages);
    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
}
```

Comment: Don't keep recreating the array every time you add something to it.  That kinda loses the old contents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take away  `camImages = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:10];` and put it in viewDidLoad.

**EDIT:** Use this instead:

```
UIImage *cameraImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
self.tempView.image = cameraImage;

if(!camImages)camImages = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

camImages = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:10];
[camImages addObject:self.tempView.image];
//self.chosenImages=camImages;
NSLog(@"the image is=%@",camImages);
[picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
```

Comment: Why -viewDidLoad, what about UIViewController life cycle?

Comment: Not specifically viewDidLoad, but not when saving the picture because it will reset the existing picture

Comment: It could be anywhere but like @RobvanderVeer said not when saving the picture.

Comment: I just wanted to say that putting this into -viewDidLoad isn't really good thing... better to -init or "lazy" property self.camImages

Comment: @Nasir Can you use breakpoints to tell me where it is crashing?

Comment: Use alloc init instead

Comment: write this in viewdidload or notcamImages = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:10];

Comment: You could if you want but it is better to add this if(!camImages)camImages = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

Comment: @Nasir In your code and take out camImages = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:10];

Comment: Take out:notcamImages = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:10]; and add the new code I told you

Answer (score 1):

The problem it's because [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:10]; actually allocates a new position in memory for a array, and your pointer camImages are pointing for a new array, losing the reference for the old one you allocated previously.

So, whenever you take a new photo, a new memory position for the array will be allocated, with just the current image.

To resolve this problem, you should allocate this array only once, and use the same memory position for the array to add your images.

As Abdullah Shafique pointed, you can allocate this array once in the some previous method, like viewDidLoad, or just use lazy instantiation, with a if in your delegate method.

```
if(!camImages){
     camImages = [NSMutableArray new];
}
```

Comment: Please, folks, remember that the `init` routine is there precisely to do this sort of initialization.  No need to add complexity to do "lazy" initialization.